# How do I find $x$ of this triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

I've this angle and wanna find to $x$. So I haven't seen a question which two angle wasn't given. If someone helps me it would be great. Also thank you all.

Comment: If all we know about the triangle is in that drawing, then $x$ could be anything, because $D$ and $E$ could be put wherever we want.

Comment: You do not, because you lack sufficient information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find $A\hat BE=120$ because the angles in $\triangle ABC$ must add to $180$

We can then find that $B\hat ED=180-x$ because angles on a line must add to $180$

Next we can find that $E\hat DA = 360 - (40+120+(180-x))  = 20 + x$ because angles in the quadrilateral $ABED$ must add to $360$

Now we can find that $E\hat DC = 180 - (20+x) = 160 - x$ because, again, angles on a line must add to $180$

Finally we can look at $\triangle EDC$ to see that  $20 + x + 160 - x = 180$

It is obvious that the $x$ will cancel out of this equation, and therefore it is impossible to find $x$ with the given diagram

Comment: Your final answer is correct. However, what you've actually shown is only that _your_ attempt to find $x$ does not work. You haven't shown that all attempts will fail. Your specific angle chasing yielded no results, but that doesn't automatically mean by itself that the answer is impossible to find.

Comment: @Arthur Why not? I have found every angle in the diagram, in terms of $x$ and shown that it is impossible to know the value of $x$

Comment: The same argument would be just as fruitless if we added measurements to all segments, but if we did that, then clearly $x$ would be fixed (at the very least, it would be possible to find with trigonometry). In that case, your "proof" would still show that $x$ can't be found, when clearly it can. An easier full proof that $x$ cannot be found is to demonstrate, with more or less explicit examples, that $x$ could be several different things.

Answer (score 0):

$$B=180-40-20=120$$
$$D=180-x-20$$

$$120+40+(180-x)+(x+20)=360$$

$$0=0$$
this proves that your question is not well-asked.
is $D $ the middle of $(
AC) $.

Comment: You haven't _really_ shown that $x$ can't be found. You've only shown that looking at the immediate triangles and quadrilaterals shown in the figure, $x$ cannot be found. More to the point, this argument would be just as fruitless if we added exact measurements to all segments, but if we did that, then clearly $x$ would be fixed.

Comment: Ah I understood.